# ESLint rule for not allowing variable declarations inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Are there any published eslint rules for pointing

Just a random example so please don't pay heed to the logic/functionality-

this as **BAD**

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.innerHtml = `${container.innerHtml}my number: ${i}`;
}
```

and suggesting this as **GOOD**:

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
    container.innerHtml = `${container.innerHtml}my number: ${i}`;
}
```

Comment: Why would the first code be bad and the second good? It's rather the other way around

Comment: You're trying to hoist what is likely constant out of a loop but there's no guarantee that it's constant

Comment: @ThomasSablik Why query the DOM(*) 5 times for an element with the id `container` instead of only once?

Comment: @Andreas just an example, focus on the variable

Comment: @AluanHaddad What if there's a gurantee?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Please explain.. You would want redeclaration and initialization of a constant every time the loop runs. I would rather bind it in an IFFE and keep it outside if scope leakage is your concern.

Comment: I support your question... I would also go with the "GOOD" example because of that exact point. Why create 5 variables with always the same content (+ query the DOM 5 times) when the content won't change in those 5 rounds of the loop

Comment: Don't declare a variable before you use it is a rule for clean code. This is a microoptimization. Don't do this if this is not your bottleneck. And your interpreter will probably optimize it for you. Clean code is more important than microoptimized code.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. This special example might be correct (can be discussed after performance tests) but _"not allowing variable declarations inside a loop"_ is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest that I could was the `no-inner-declarations` rule as an ESLint core [rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-inner-declarations).